# DataPower Web Service Proxy getting 500 error

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, ibm-datapower

I got a problem with DataPower. I'm trying to set ws proxy up, but it keeps throwing http 500. I will provide wsdl, java code below.

I've set Remote Endpoint Host as my ip (not localhost):8080 - i host this ws on Eclipse + Tomcat, and Local Endpoint Host to ip of VM - instance of DataPower Gateway Trial with unused port (i use 2911). I uploaded wsdl file and set it up ofc.

I'm trying to test it with SOAP UI, by sending POST request with getUserName method invocation to http://VMip/WebServiceProject/services/UsersCatalog but i get error 500. I think i tried everything but still cant get it working. Please help!

UsersCatalog.wsdl

```
   <wsdl:message name="setUserDataResponse">

      <wsdl:part element="impl:setUserDataResponse" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:message name="getUserDataRequest">

      <wsdl:part element="impl:getUserData" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:message name="setUserDataRequest">

      <wsdl:part element="impl:setUserData" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:message name="getUserNameResponse">

      <wsdl:part element="impl:getUserNameResponse" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:message name="getUserDataResponse">

      <wsdl:part element="impl:getUserDataResponse" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:message name="getUserNameRequest">

      <wsdl:part element="impl:getUserName" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:portType name="UsersCatalog">

      <wsdl:operation name="getUserData">

         <wsdl:input message="impl:getUserDataRequest" name="getUserDataRequest">

       </wsdl:input>

         <wsdl:output message="impl:getUserDataResponse" name="getUserDataResponse">

       </wsdl:output>

      </wsdl:operation>

      <wsdl:operation name="setUserData">

         <wsdl:input message="impl:setUserDataRequest" name="setUserDataRequest">

       </wsdl:input>

         <wsdl:output message="impl:setUserDataResponse" name="setUserDataResponse">

       </wsdl:output>

      </wsdl:operation>

      <wsdl:operation name="getUserName">

         <wsdl:input message="impl:getUserNameRequest" name="getUserNameRequest">

       </wsdl:input>

         <wsdl:output message="impl:getUserNameResponse" name="getUserNameResponse">

       </wsdl:output>

      </wsdl:operation>

   </wsdl:portType>

   <wsdl:binding name="UsersCatalogSoapBinding" type="impl:UsersCatalog">

      <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

      <wsdl:operation name="getUserData">

         <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>

         <wsdl:input name="getUserDataRequest">

            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

         </wsdl:input>

         <wsdl:output name="getUserDataResponse">

            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

         </wsdl:output>

      </wsdl:operation>

      <wsdl:operation name="setUserData">

         <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>

         <wsdl:input name="setUserDataRequest">

            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

         </wsdl:input>

         <wsdl:output name="setUserDataResponse">

            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

         </wsdl:output>

      </wsdl:operation>

      <wsdl:operation name="getUserName">

         <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>

         <wsdl:input name="getUserNameRequest">

            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

         </wsdl:input>

         <wsdl:output name="getUserNameResponse">

            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

         </wsdl:output>

      </wsdl:operation>

   </wsdl:binding>

   <wsdl:service name="UsersCatalogService">

      <wsdl:port binding="impl:UsersCatalogSoapBinding" name="UsersCatalog">

         <wsdlsoap:address location="http://10.57.129.63:8080/WebServiceProject/services/UsersCatalog"/>

      </wsdl:port>

   </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

UsersCatalog (userImpl is just class with 2 fields - userName and userAddress + getters and setter)

```
package wtp;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class UsersCatalog implements User{
    public static final User userImpl = new UserImpl();

    @WebMethod
    public String getUserName() {
        return userImpl.getUserName();
    }

    @WebMethod
    public String getUserData() {
        return userImpl.getUserData();
    }

    @WebMethod
    public void setUserData(String userName, String userAddress) {
        userImpl.setUserData(userName, userAddress);
    }
}
```

Logs as Anders requested:

```
11:54:45    network         debug       16945   response    10.57.129.63    0x80e0039e  xmlfirewall (web-mgmt): url-open: response code 200
11:54:45    multistep       debug       3044    request                     0x80c00004  xmlfirewall (map): Protocol layer did not supply content-type
11:54:45    multistep       debug       3044    request                     0x80c00004  xmlfirewall (map): Protocol layer did not supply content-type
11:54:41    memory-report   debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80e00690  wsgw (User.wsp): Response Finished: memory used 0
11:54:41    ws-proxy        information 33491   error       10.57.129.63    0x80e000b6  wsgw (User.wsp): No match from processing policy 'User.wsp' for code '0x01130006'
11:54:41    ws-proxy        warning     33491               10.57.129.63    0x80c0007b  wsm-stylepolicy (User.wsp): No error rule is matched.
11:54:41    ws-proxy        debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x810000d6  wsgw (User.wsp): Match: Received value [http://www.datapower.com/fragment-id#dp.all()] matches WSDL component type 'fragmentid' 'getUserData'.
11:54:41    ws-proxy        debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x810000d6  wsgw (User.wsp): Match: Received value [http://www.datapower.com/fragment-id#dp.all()] matches WSDL component type 'fragmentid' 'getUserData'.
11:54:41    ws-proxy        error       33491   error       10.57.129.63    0x01130006  wsgw (User.wsp): Failed to establish a backside connection
11:54:41    ws-proxy        error       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80e00126  wsgw (User.wsp): Valid backside connection could not be established: Failed to establish a backside connection, url: http://10.57.129.63:2911/WebServiceProject/services/UsersCatalog
11:54:41    ws-proxy        error       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80e00627  wsgw (User.wsp): Error occurred (port error) when connecting to URL 'http://10.57.129.63:2911/WebServiceProject/services/UsersCatalog'
11:54:41    network         error       33491                               0x80e00049  xmlmgr (default): Host connection failed to establish: 10.57.129.63 : tcp port 2911
11:54:41    network         error       33491                               0x00b30009  xmlmgr (default): Host connection could not be established
11:54:41    network         debug       3471                                0x80e006bd  A hangup error occurred on socket (119). Error details (111: Connection refused). Local(10.57.129.109:25227) - Remote(n/a)
11:54:41    ws-proxy        debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80e00536  wsgw (User.wsp): HTTP Header-Retention:Compression Policy: Off, URL: /WebServiceProject/services/UsersCatalog
11:54:41    ws-proxy        debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80e00536  wsgw (User.wsp): HTTP Header-Retention:Header-Retention Policy:MQMD = OFF. MQMD Header = (NULL), URL: http://10.57.129.63:2911/WebServiceProject/services/UsersCatalog
11:54:41    ws-proxy        debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80e00536  wsgw (User.wsp): HTTP Header-Retention:Header-Retention Policy: Range = OFF. Range Header = (NULL), URL: http://10.57.129.63:2911/WebServiceProject/services/UsersCatalog
11:54:41    ws-proxy        debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80e00536  wsgw (User.wsp): HTTP Header-Retention:Header-Retention Policy: Accept-Encoding = OFF. Accept-Encoding Header = gzip,deflate, URL: http://10.57.129.63:2911/WebServiceProject/services/UsersCatalog
11:54:41    ws-proxy        debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80e00536  wsgw (User.wsp): HTTP Header-Retention:Header-Retention Policy: TE = OFF. TE Header = (NULL), URL: http://10.57.129.63:2911/WebServiceProject/services/UsersCatalog
11:54:41    network         debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80e003ca  xmlmgr (default): Attempting TCP connect to 10.57.129.63
11:54:41    multistep       information 33491   request     10.57.129.63    0x80c00002  wsgw (User.wsp): rule (User.wsp_default_request-rule): #2 results: Generated from INPUT. Results stored in OUTPUT. completed OK.
11:54:41    memory-report   debug       33491   request     10.57.129.63    0x80e0068d  wsgw (User.wsp): Processing [Rule (User.wsp_default_request-rule), Action ('User.wsp_default_request-rule_defaultaction_result', results()), Input(INPUT), Output(OUTPUT)] finished: memory used 342160
11:54:41    multistep       information 33491   request     10.57.129.63    0x80c00002  wsgw (User.wsp): rule (User.wsp_default_request-rule): #1 slm: 'INPUT User.wsp' completed OK.
11:54:41    memory-report   debug       33491   request     10.57.129.63    0x80e0068d  wsgw (User.wsp): Processing [Rule (User.wsp_default_request-rule), Action ('User.wsp_default_request-rule_defaultaction_slm', slm(User.wsp)), Input(INPUT), Output(NULL)] finished: memory used 0
11:54:41    xmlfilter       information 33491   request     10.57.129.63    0x80c00036  wsgw (User.wsp): Accept set.
11:54:41    xslt            debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80a002ac  xmlmgr (default): xslt Compilation Request: Found in cache store:///dp/slmpolicy.xsl.
11:54:41    xslt            debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80a002aa  xmlmgr (default): xslt Compilation Request: Checking cache for URL 'store:///dp/slmpolicy.xsl'.
11:54:41    multistep       debug       33491   request     10.57.129.63    0x80c0004e  wsgw (User.wsp): Stylesheet URL to compile is 'store:///dp/slmpolicy.xsl'
11:54:41    ws-proxy        information 33491               10.57.129.63    0x80a002a4  xmlmgr (default): wsdl Compilation Request: Compilation complete of URL 'local:///UsersCatalog.wsdl'. Memory used 1349568 bytes.
11:54:41    ws-proxy        debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80a002a3  xmlmgr (default): wsdl Compilation Request: Beginning compilation of URL 'local:///UsersCatalog.wsdl'.
11:54:41    ws-proxy        debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80a002af  xmlmgr (default): wsdl Compilation Request: Not in cache. Compiling 'local:///UsersCatalog.wsdl'.
11:54:41    ws-proxy        debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80a002aa  xmlmgr (default): wsdl Compilation Request: Checking cache for URL 'local:///UsersCatalog.wsdl'.
11:54:41    xmlparse        debug       33491   request     10.57.129.63    0x80e003ab  wsgw (User.wsp): Finished parsing: http://10.57.129.110:2912/WebServiceProject/services/UsersCatalog
11:54:41    xmlparse        debug       33491   request     10.57.129.63    0x80e003a6  wsgw (User.wsp): Parsing document: 'http://10.57.129.110:2912/WebServiceProject/services/UsersCatalog'
11:54:41    multistep       warning     33491   request     10.57.129.63    0x00340027  wsgw (User.wsp): Multistep Probe enabled
11:54:41    memory-report   debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80e0068c  wsgw (User.wsp): Request Started: memory used 0
11:54:41    ws-proxy        information 33491   request     10.57.129.63    0x80e000b4  wsm-stylepolicy (User.wsp): rule (User.wsp_default_request-rule): selected via match 'User.wsp_match_all' from processing policy 'User.wsp'
11:54:41    http            debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x81000171  Matching (User.wsp_match_all): Match: Received URL [/WebServiceProject/services/UsersCatalog] matches rule '*'
11:54:41    ws-proxy        debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x810000d6  wsgw (User.wsp): Match: Received value [http://www.datapower.com/fragment-id#dp.all()] matches WSDL component type 'fragmentid' 'getUserData'.
11:54:41    ws-proxy        information 33491               10.57.129.63    0x80e00383  source-http (handler): WS-Proxy selected: 'User.wsp'. Operation 'getUserData' matches all criteria.
11:54:41    ws-proxy        debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80e00384  source-http (handler): WS-Proxy User.wsp operation getUserName does not match SOAP operation as required by WS-I BP1.0/1.1 R2744 or R2745: received (getUserData) required (getUserName). Received protocol 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/', required protocol 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/'. Received SOAPAction ((null)) required SOAPAction (). SOAPAction policy is lax.
11:54:41    ws-proxy        warning     33491               10.57.129.63    0x80e004b8  source-http (handler): Unrecognized content type so SOAP Action header '' will be ignored
11:54:41    ws-proxy        debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80e00384  source-http (handler): WS-Proxy User.wsp operation setUserData does not match SOAP operation as required by WS-I BP1.0/1.1 R2744 or R2745: received (getUserData) required (setUserData). Received protocol 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/', required protocol 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/'. Received SOAPAction ((null)) required SOAPAction (). SOAPAction policy is lax.
11:54:41    ws-proxy        warning     33491               10.57.129.63    0x80e004b8  source-http (handler): Unrecognized content type so SOAP Action header '' will be ignored
11:54:41    ws-proxy        debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80e00384  source-http (handler): WS-Proxy User.wsp operation getUserData does not match SOAP operation as required by WS-I BP1.0/1.1 R2744 or R2745: received (getUserData) required (getUserData). Received protocol 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/', required protocol 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/'. Received SOAPAction ((null)) required SOAPAction (). SOAPAction policy is lax.
11:54:41    ws-proxy        warning     33491               10.57.129.63    0x80e004b8  source-http (handler): Unrecognized content type so SOAP Action header '' will be ignored
11:54:41    ws-proxy        debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80e00384  source-http (handler): WS-Proxy User.wsp operation getUserName does not match SOAP operation as required by WS-I BP1.0/1.1 R2744 or R2745: received (getUserData) required (getUserName). Received protocol 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/', required protocol 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/'. Received SOAPAction () required SOAPAction (). SOAPAction policy is lax.
11:54:41    ws-proxy        debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80e00384  source-http (handler): WS-Proxy User.wsp operation setUserData does not match SOAP operation as required by WS-I BP1.0/1.1 R2744 or R2745: received (getUserData) required (setUserData). Received protocol 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/', required protocol 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/'. Received SOAPAction () required SOAPAction (). SOAPAction policy is lax.
11:54:41    xmlparse        debug       33491   request     10.57.129.63    0x80e003a9  xmlmgr (default): Parsing http://10.57.129.110:2912/WebServiceProject/services/UsersCatalog stopped on XPath match
11:54:41    xmlparse        debug       33491   request     10.57.129.63    0x80e003a6  xmlmgr (default): Parsing document: 'http://10.57.129.110:2912/WebServiceProject/services/UsersCatalog'
11:54:41    xslt            debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80a002ac  xmlmgr (default): patterns Compilation Request: Found in cache expr:////*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*.
11:54:41    xslt            debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80a002aa  xmlmgr (default): patterns Compilation Request: Checking cache for URL 'expr:////*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*'.
11:54:41    ws-proxy        debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80e0037d  source-http (handler): WS-Proxy User.wsp operation setUserData matches address (10.57.129.110:2912) url (/WebServiceProject/services/UsersCatalog). SOAP operation and Action will be evaluated.
11:54:41    ws-proxy        debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80e0037d  source-http (handler): WS-Proxy User.wsp operation getUserName matches address (10.57.129.110:2912) url (/WebServiceProject/services/UsersCatalog). SOAP operation and Action will be evaluated.
11:54:41    ws-proxy        debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80e0037d  source-http (handler): WS-Proxy User.wsp operation getUserData matches address (10.57.129.110:2912) url (/WebServiceProject/services/UsersCatalog). SOAP operation and Action will be evaluated.
11:54:41    ws-proxy        debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80e0037d  source-http (handler): WS-Proxy User.wsp operation setUserData matches address (10.57.129.110:2912) url (/WebServiceProject/services/UsersCatalog). SOAP operation and Action will be evaluated.
11:54:41    ws-proxy        debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80e0037d  source-http (handler): WS-Proxy User.wsp operation getUserName matches address (10.57.129.110:2912) url (/WebServiceProject/services/UsersCatalog). SOAP operation and Action will be evaluated.
11:54:41    ws-proxy        debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80e0037d  source-http (handler): WS-Proxy User.wsp operation getUserData matches address (10.57.129.110:2912) url (/WebServiceProject/services/UsersCatalog). SOAP operation and Action will be evaluated.
11:54:41    mpgw            debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80e00140  source-http (handler): Generating chunked response stream to front
11:54:41    mpgw            debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80e0013f  source-http (handler): Found content length 207 HTTP input
11:54:41    mpgw            debug       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80e0013b  source-http (handler): HTTP Transaction # 1 on this TCP connection
11:54:41    mpgw            information 33491               10.57.129.63    0x80e0013a  source-http (handler): Received HTTP/1.1 POST for /WebServiceProject/services/UsersCatalog from 10.57.129.63
11:54:34    network         debug       16865   response    10.57.129.63    0x80e0039f  xmlfirewall (web-mgmt): url-open: Finished parsing response from: http://127.0.0.1:63503/
11:54:34    network         debug       16865   response    10.57.129.63    0x80e0039e  xmlfirewall (web-mgmt): url-open: response code 200
11:54:34    multistep       debug       2996    request                     0x80c00004  xmlfirewall (map): Protocol layer did not supply content-type
11:54:34    multistep       debug       2996    request                     0x80c00004  xmlfirewall (map): Protocol layer did not supply content-type
11:54:34    network         debug       3968    response    10.57.129.63    0x80e0039f  xmlfirewall (web-mgmt): url-open: Finished parsing response from: http://127.0.0.1:63503/
11:54:34    network         debug       3968    response    10.57.129.63    0x80e0039e  xmlfirewall (web-mgmt): url-open: response code 200
11:54:34    multistep       debug       20309   request                     0x80c00004  xmlfirewall (map): Protocol layer did not supply content-type
11:54:34    multistep       debug       20309   request                     0x80c00004  xmlfirewall (map): Protocol layer did not supply content-type
11:54:34    network         debug       3968    response    10.57.129.63    0x80e0039f  xmlfirewall (web-mgmt): url-open: Finished parsing response from: http://127.0.0.1:63503/
11:54:34    network         debug       3968    response    10.57.129.63    0x80e0039e  xmlfirewall (web-mgmt): url-open: response code 200
11:54:34    multistep       debug       20293   request                     0x80c00004  xmlfirewall (map): Protocol layer did not supply content-type
11:54:34    multistep       debug       20293   request                     0x80c00004  xmlfirewall (map): Protocol layer did not supply content-type
11:54:34    network         debug       3968    response    10.57.129.63    0x80e0039f  xmlfirewall (web-mgmt): url-open: Finished parsing response from: http://127.0.0.1:63503/
11:54:34    network         debug       3968    response    10.57.129.63    0x80e0039e  xmlfirewall (web-mgmt): url-open: response code 200
11:54:34    multistep       debug       20277   request                     0x80c00004  xmlfirewall (map): Protocol layer did not supply content-type
11:54:34    multistep       debug       20277   request                     0x80c00004  xmlfirewall (map): Protocol layer did not supply content-type
11:54:34    network         debug       3952    response    10.57.129.63    0x80e0039f  xmlfirewall (web-mgmt): url-open: Finished parsing response from: http://127.0.0.1:63503/
11:54:34    network         debug       3952    response    10.57.129.63    0x80e0039e  xmlfirewall (web-mgmt): url-open: response code 200
11:54:34    multistep       debug       2964    request                     0x80c00004  xmlfirewall (map): Protocol layer did not supply content-type
11:54:34    multistep       debug       2964    request                     0x80c00004  xmlfirewall (map): Protocol layer did not supply content-type
11:54:33    network         debug       16817   response    10.57.129.63    0x80e0039f  xmlfirewall (web-mgmt): url-open: Finished parsing response from: http://127.0.0.1:63503/
11:54:33    network         debug       16817   response    10.57.129.63    0x80e0039e  xmlfirewall (web-mgmt): url-open: response code 200
11:54:33    multistep       debug       20245   request                     0x80c00004  xmlfirewall (map): Protocol layer did not supply content-type
11:54:33    multistep       debug       20245   request                     0x80c00004  xmlfirewall (map): Protocol layer did not supply content-type
11:54:33    network         debug       16817   response    10.57.129.63    0x80e0039f  xmlfirewall (web-mgmt): url-open: Finished parsing response from: http://127.0.0.1:63503/
```

This part is most important i think:

```
11:54:41    ws-proxy        error       33491   error       10.57.129.63    0x01130006  wsgw (User.wsp): Failed to establish a backside connection
11:54:41    ws-proxy        error       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80e00126  wsgw (User.wsp): Valid backside connection could not be established: Failed to establish a backside connection, url: http://10.57.129.63:2911/WebServiceProject/services/UsersCatalog
11:54:41    ws-proxy        error       33491               10.57.129.63    0x80e00627  wsgw (User.wsp): Error occurred (port error) when connecting to URL 'http://10.57.129.63:2911/WebServiceProject/services/UsersCatalog'
11:54:41    network         error       33491                               0x80e00049  xmlmgr (default): Host connection failed to establish: 10.57.129.63 : tcp port 2911
11:54:41    network         error       33491                               0x00b30009  xmlmgr (default): Host connection could not be established
```

I asked my admin if our firewall isn't blocking incoming traffic, but it's allowed.

I discovered that DataPower accepts request, but it fails to make it's way to host (Tomcat).

I was thinking that it might be a problem with VM network setting, but it throws same error both on bridged and host-only.

Comment: Can you set it to debug logging and share the logs?

Comment: added logs and some extra info. would be glad if you'd answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a connection refused which most likely means you've hit a firewall. 
Use the troubleshooting tool in DataPower to do a connection test on the port and IP you need to connect to and check that you get a connection. 
If you do, then you have some issue with the Java service. 
If not then check any firewall and route between DataPower and the target server.

Make sure you have the NIC's properly set in DataPower if you are using more than one IP/NIC. Only one NIC should have a default gateway, the rest static routes.

Comment: i had connection refused on port 2911. to avoid this i've set tomcat to port 80. now i get some parse error (wtf?): 
wsgw (user1.wsp): rule (user1.wsp_default_response-rule): Implied action Parsing input as SOAP, attempt pipeline. failed: illegal character '4' at offset 0 of 10.57.129.103:80/WebServiceProject/services/UsersCatalog
and another one: 

wsgw (user1.wsp): illegal character '4' at offset 0 of http://10.57.129.103:80/WebServiceProject/services/UsersCatalog
i dont get it, is that possible to take a peek on this response? god, it starts to be really annoying

Comment: i realised that there is a way to take a peek on it, by packet capture. however it led me to even more confusion. flow: soapUI post with xml with method invocation -> datapower responds post with same xml method invocation -> my localhost post 404 to dp (why?) -> dp post 500 to soapUI

Comment: Just enable the Probe on the WSP. You most likely are not returning valid XML/SOAP

Comment: well, i wasnt precise enough i think. another 500 is thrown - now it has additional (from server) statement. of course, when i send same request without dp it returns valid xml. i enabled probe, but still no luck i think. response is highlighted red, and its content is empty, but headers are good i think, nevertheless in service variables there is this illegal character '4' error again. i have no idea where to look for solution. your help is priceless  :) 
[link](http://pastebin.com/HmUE5G1W) these are request and responses,

Comment: i think i got it. i mean the reason. i have set remote endpoint host to default gateway:80 . when i post a request from soapUI to default gateway i get 404 aswell. how to redirect from this to localhost where my tomcat is? is default gateway only way to connect from vm to host? there is no good information provided on the web

Comment: allright, got it. without your help it wont be possible, thank you very much!